# Docker compose v2 & v3 spec support by ECS optimized AMI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

In this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html), it is mentioned that, any ECS container instance run below version:

A Docker daemon running at least version 1.9.0

---

Test and release environments are created within ECS environment.

We have test and release environments composed using docker-compose v2 & v3 spec.

Does docker daemon >= 1.9.0 support docker-compose specs(V2 & V3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the compatibility table [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/), also to make one thing clear, docker-compose is depended on Docker version, not docker engine on docker-compose.

[image]

You also not bound to use old AMI, you can explore AWS ECS AMI with latest docker version.

**Amazon ECS-optimized AMI Versions**

> This topic lists the current and previous versions of the Amazon
>   ECS-optimized AMIs and their corresponding versions of the Amazon ECS
>   container agent, Docker, and the ecs-init package.

[image]
[ecs-ami-versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-ami-versions.html)

Comment: So, how do I know, if docker version `18.06.1-ce` support docker compose v2 spec?